# How to get segue identifier

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uistoryboardsegue

I'm pretty nooby, just saying that before I start.

What I'm trying to do is make a table of cells, and when a cell is touched it displays an image depending on which cell was touched. Now, I thought that there would be a way to tell which cell was touched and set the UIImageView image accordingly, or am I going to have as many views as table cells and have loads of segues? Basically what I'm trying to do is get the segue identifier and use it to set the UIImageView image.

Answer (score 6):

You can get the segue identifier with this method, which is called if a segue is pushed:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YourChoiseMadeInStoryboard"]) {
  ...
  //to access the destination ViewController do this
  AViewControllerClass *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`UIStoryboardSegue` is designed to facilitate the transition between two instances of `UIViewController`. What you're trying to do doesn't require segues at all. You want to toggle an image view on a cell when it is tapped. You only need to implement the `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method on `UITableViewDelegate`.

**Edit** I'm assuming you already have an ivar for your `UIImageView` called `imageView`. You will also need an ivar for an `NSArray` that holds all of the images. The image at each index will correspond to each row in the table. Establish your array somewhere like `-viewDidLoad` and assume that it is called `imageArray`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Get the cell at the selected index path
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // After being tapped, set the image view to some image
    self.imageView.image = [self.imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clearer; I have a UIImageView that is separate from my tableview, I want to have all the cells connected to the ImageView and change which image is displayed in the ImageView depending on the cell touched. E.g., a cell called 'cat' would display a cat in the ImageView, not in the cell.